# About Flex tree localization

Tags: apache-flex, localization

I am using mx:XML as data source for mx:Tree, and would like to show localized values.

The XML looks like:

```
<myTag label="component.mytextKey.txt"/>
```

. And I have properties defined in my properties file, like

```
component.mytextKey.txt=Translated Text for my textKey.
```

Then in mx:Tree, I specify labelField="@label" to show the value.

mx:Tree displays "component.mytextKey.txt" as untranslated text.

I tried to use `@Resource(key='@label`, `bundle='mybundle')` and `{resourceManager.getString('mybundle',@label)}` as value for labelFIeld in mx:Tree. All no luck.

I also tried to specify value of as:
   
Still no luck, the tree is trying to show the label as is, instead of showing evaludated value.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Resource is a build-time command. You can try to use labelFunction and ResourceManager to load your localization data as the following:

```
<mx:Tree labelFunction="{myLabelFunction}" />

function myLabelFunction(item:XML):String{ 
    return ResourceManager.getInstance().getString("BundleName", item.@label.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget anything that isn't to be treated as a string literal, needs to be wrapped in the binding braces (eg {}). This tells the compiler it's a derived value from a method, property, etc...